# How to disable RSS but still using multiple RX queues in DPDK?

Tags: dpdk

Is there a way to disable Receive Side Scaling but still using multiple RX queues in a hardware round robin fashion in DPDK? I set mq_mode to `ETH_MQ_RX_NONE` rather than `ETH_MQ_RX_RSS` but it seems like there is only one queue avaliable when receive packets.

Comment: please check your dev_configure for number of RX queues?

Comment: I do set multiple RX queues and one TX queue in dev_configure, but only the first RX queue can receive packets. Can I ask if it should be doing round robin if ETH_MQ_RX_NONE works?

Comment: RSS is diabled with ETH_MQ_RX_NONE, the default queue on which packets will be received is queue 0. this is the right behaviour, if you want Round robin or specific queue you should use RTE_FLOW. As per the current question or information I do not see the same. Please update with information with DPDK version, NIC PMD, and sample code.

Comment: I expressed myself wrong. What I mean with only one queue working is that all the packets went to queue 0 but not the other queues. If the default queue is queue 0, then the configuration is working and there isn't any problem for now. Thank you for your help and please put your last comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS is diabled with ETH_MQ_RX_NONE, the default queue on which packets will be received is queue 0. this is the right behaviour, if you want Round robin or specific queue you should use RTE_FLOW. As per the current question or information I do not see the same. Please update with information with DPDK version, NIC PMD, and sample code.

Comment: I was having the same problem. But in symmetric_multiprocess example they used .rss_hf=ETH_RSS_IP, it still routing all traffic to queue 0. lets say I have traffic coming from 10 different IP's and I have 2 rx queue and I want each of those queues to get traffic from 5 fixed IP's (faster cache locality). Now what should I change/do in general? look into rte_eth_conf.rxmode/rte_eth_conf.rx_adv_conf or rte_flow ? I haven't looked fully into rte_flow but it seemed like adding rule for longer time. I just wanna divide my traffic and later process.